# C++ friend template function - minGW error but not VS2015

Tags: c++, templates, friend-function, template-function

The following code compiles without a problem with Visual Studio 2015 but with minGW gets the warning and error shown below it:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
class Array
{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<ElemType, SIZE> &value);

    ElemType operator[](int index) const;

private:
    ElemType elements[SIZE];
};

template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<ElemType, SIZE> &value);

template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<ElemType, SIZE> &value)
{
    out << elements[0];
    return out;
}

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=c++98 -c Test.cpp
Test.cpp:7:79: warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array<ElemType, SIZE>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
Test.cpp:7:79: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) 
Test.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array<ElemType, SIZE>&)':
Test.cpp:21:11: error: 'elements' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm far from an expert on some of this stuff so I'm not sure what the issue is.  It seems like it's telling me it needs the follwoing code just before the friend declaration in the class itself, but when I put it there it causes other compilation errors:

```
template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
```

Thanks in advance!

After making the changes suggested by @Trevor Hickey in his post below the warning about the friend template function went away.  However, I still get the error about "elements" (in the friend function) not being declared in scope.

Comment: Does it still throw an error, without the pedantic flags? (-pedantic -pedantic-errors)

Comment: Try `out << value.elements[0];` or `out << value[0];` since you defined `operator[]` for `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two separate problems in your code. The easier one is that `out << elements[0];` should be `out << value.elements[0];`.  This is because you want to print the element that is a member of the parameter `value`.   Remember that we are in a non-member function here, there is no `this` and no members you can access by unqualified name.

The other one is known as the [template friends problem](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends).  So far you only get a warning, but if you try to compile a complete program you get an error. I added the code:

```
int main() { Array<int, 5> a; std::cout << a; }
```

and the error appears:

```
undefined reference to `std::ostream& operator<< <int, 5>(std::ostream&, Array<int, 5> const&)'
```

The problem is that your code:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<ElemType, SIZE> &value);
```

actually declares that there is a **non-template** function which will be the friend to this instance of `Array`.  Later, when you write `cout << a` in `main`, the compiler matches that `<<` to this non-template declaration. It never gets so far as the body for `operator<<` that you provided later, and so never instantiates a copy of that body, hence the undefined reference error.

One way to fix this is to explicitly instantiate the body. But this is lame as you'd have to write an explicit instantiation for each possible instantiateion of `Array` that occurs for your code. So we won't do this.

The simplest solution is to put the body of `operator<<` inline in the class definition.

The other option is to declare that `operator<<` is a template function.

Trevor Hickey's code shows one way of doing this, although that has a drawback that `Array<A, B>::elements` can be accessed by `Array<C, D>::operator<<`.

A more secure way is to declare the `operator<<` before the class:

```
template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
class Array;

template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<ElemType, SIZE> &value);
```

and then the rest of your code as it was before. Now, the `friend` declaration in the class will match the pre-existing template, instead of declaring a new non-template.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the template paramters from the class, but the function itself is not a template function.  It needs to be a template function as seen in the definition.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
class Array
{
    template<typename T, int U>
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<T, U> &value);

    ElemType operator[](int index) const;

private:
    ElemType elements[SIZE];
};

template<typename ElemType, int SIZE>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<ElemType, SIZE> &value)
{
    out << value.elements[0];
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggest but still get the following regarding the elements member: **mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=c++98  -c Test.cpp
Test.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array<ElemType, SIZE>&)':**
Test.cpp:19:12: error: 'elements' was not declared in this scope

Comment: I'm sorry for the messy comment above.  How do I get things on separate lines in a comment?  Pressing the Enter key merely exits the comment.

Comment: @BenevolentDeity you can't insert line breaks in comments, but you can use backticks `` to use code formatting. In this specific case, I think this information belongs in your question as an edit though.